# Passing Image between View Controllers is not working in presenting modal view

Tags: ios, object

i am trying to pass an image from one view controller(containing collection view) to another view controller, but it is not happening. I am new to iOS objective c. Can anyone please tell me the solution.
here is my code...

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    DetailedAlbumViewController *davc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailedAlbumViewController"];

    AlbumPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (AlbumPhotoCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image = cell.imageView.image;

    [davc setImage:image];

    //davc.imageView.image = image;


    [self presentModalViewController:davc animated:YES];
}
```

in my second view controller...

```
- (void) setImage:(UIImage *) image{

    UIImage *someImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    someImage = image;       // image is passing upto here.. i.e. someImage is being allocated with the image passed from first view controller..

    self.imageView.image = someImage;     // here it is showing nil

}
```

i used debug console.. the output is..

```
(lldb) po someImage
<UIImage: 0x79eb8590>, {500, 347}

(lldb) po self.imageView.image
 nil
```

Comment: why don't `- (void) setImage:(UIImage *) image{
    self.imageView.image = image;     // here it is showing nil
}` and try declaring `DetailedAlbumViewController *davc` in your viewController where you are presenting

Comment: for that also same thing is happening.. then i thought i could allocate some memory for it. So i did like that..

Comment: Sorry for asking again... i initialized the davc as a property.. it is not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass image not set image to destination controller . so you need to make code as below .

**In DetailedAlbumViewController**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *yourImage ;
```

**In viewDidLoad of DetailedAlbumViewControllerv**

```
[self setImage:self.yourImage];
```

**While cell clicked**

**Suggestion** - You need to use didselectItemAtIndexpath instead of didDeselectItemAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    DetailedAlbumViewController *davc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailedAlbumViewController"];

    AlbumPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (AlbumPhotoCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image = cell.imageView.image;
    davc.yourImage = image

    [self presentModalViewController:davc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you might have `self.imageView` nil

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a property of type UIImage in DetailedAlbumViewController.

```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *someImage ;
```

Next assign the current image to it as shown in below code snippet.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


DetailedAlbumViewController *davc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailedAlbumViewController"];

AlbumPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (AlbumPhotoCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImage *image = cell.imageView.image;

davc.someImage = image;

[self presentModalViewController:davc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create property on `DetailedAlbumViewController` header file, call it as `selectedImage`

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *selectedImage;
```

Change your implementation as like below

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    DetailedAlbumViewController *davc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailedAlbumViewController"];

    AlbumPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (AlbumPhotoCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image = cell.imageView.image;

    davc.selectedImage = image;


    [self presentModalViewController:davc animated:YES];
}
```

In `DetailedAlbumViewController` implementation file `viewWillAppear` update your imageView image.

And make sure your imageView is not `nil`. Connect `UIImageView` from your `Storyboard`/`xib` Else allocate and position it at the time of `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.imagView == nil) {
       //allocate and position the imageView
      self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    }
    self.imageView.image = self.selectedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIImage *image = cell.imageView.image;

image may be nil, you need to confirm once and if image is coming then you can put

```
    if (self.imagView == nil) {
           //allocate and position the imageView
          self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        }
self.imageView.image = self.selectedImage;
```

inside 
viewDidAppear rather than viewWillAppear method.